# Why was the "Companies" option moved to the "PUBLIC" section in the left navigation bar since April 1, 2022?

Tags: discussion, support, left-nav

I recently noticed that there was an option in the sidebar of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) named "[Companies](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?so_medium=askubuntu&so_source=SiteNav)" under the *PUBLIC* section.

[image]

This is how it previously looked ([before April 1, 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331225520/https://askubuntu.com/)):

[image]

The "Companies" option was under *FIND A JOB* section before April 1, 2022.

I noticed that this option started appearing in *PUBLIC* section since April 1, 2022 (according to [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220401234507/https://askubuntu.com/)), i.e., the day after Stack Overflow Jobs was discontinued ([March 31, 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293)).

- Why was this change made?
- Was the community informed about this change?
- How does the "Companies" option have any relevance to the PUBLIC section (also, can you please define what does "PUBLIC" exactly mean)?
- Why is *Companies* having more priority in sorting compared to Unanswered questions?

Comment: "Public" means "not Stack Overflow for Teams".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 not accurate. Some sites have more menu items, e.g. Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The change was made because the functionality of Stack Overflow [Jobs and Developer Story was removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) or in the company's terminology sunsetted.

> This includes all job listings, saved searches, applications, messages, recommended job matches, job ads, developer story, saved resumes, and the salary calculator.

So that means the FIND A JOB menu item was removed but the company still wanted to keep the Companies menu item and functionality per the announcement post.

> Developers and technologists often want to learn about companies as they begin to evaluate opportunities in order to understand things like the company culture, the work/life balance, the social and environmental policies, the tech stack, and the learning and development opportunities companies offer. This is collectively referred to as “Employer Branding.”

Having no parent menu item they simply moved the Companies menu item into the existing menu.

There are actually as many as three menus. PUBLIC, COLLECTIVES and TEAMS. If you're not in any teams or collectives you just see the PUBLIC menu item. Teams are private i.e. their questions and answers are only visible if you're in that team. Even the team name itself is private.  Collectives are semi-private in that only certain people can post. In contrast the main sites are public i.e. anyone can post and read the questions and answers.

Stack Overflow doesn't have an unanswered menu item so I imagine it was simply easier to show all the fixed items before any site specific items.

Comment: SO actually has three menu items, it has Collectives. So one can say Companies might better fit in its own menu item as it's not directly related to the Q&A model of the site.

Comment: Probably but one menu item on its own is a bit lonely.

Comment: Possibly but it feels wierd that things "Organic" to our sites like meta and chat arn't there and companies is. A better question might be how much value this ads

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that depends on who you consider important in terms of value gained, ;)